# req.body changes value after assignment to variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i don't really understand what's happening here and would appreciate pointing out flaws in my assumptions:

```
 putUser: async (req, res, next) => {
        console.log('test1', req.body)
        let data = req.body
        data["local.password"] = 'xd121244212141243'
        console.log('test2', data)
        console.log('test3', req.body)
```

this block of code produces result as:

```
test1 { 'local.username': 'name','local.password': 'passwordToChange' }
test2 { 'local.username': 'name','local.password': 'xd121244212141243' }
test3 { 'local.username': 'name','local.password': 'xd121244212141243' }
```

So the question is, why does value of req.body changes ? Is this because we are pointing to the object instead of making new one ?

Comment: _Is this because we are pointing to the object instead of making new one ?_ - 
Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this because we are pointing to the object instead of making new one ?

Yup.

```
 let data = req.body
```

That copies the reference to the object from `req.body` to `data`, so they are both *referencing* the same object. To copy instead:

```
 let data = { ...req.body };
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct both data and req.body point to the same location in memory.

You could fix this in many ways see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript) for most of them.

One way which I think should suit your specific case is

```
let data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body))
```

though it isn't particularily efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, see this [S.O. post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value) about it.

Tl;dr: "*Javascript is always pass by value, but when a variable refers to an object (including arrays), the "value" is a reference to the object.*"